# How do we choose the color and combination for home interior

Tags: tile, paint, interior, design, laminate

I'd like to decide the colours for my home interior walls( Front yard, Hall, Bed room , Dining room , kitchen, bathroom and back yard and also I'd like the colors to match with tiles color which is in white.

I'd like to choose colors(Lamination) for TV set,Show case in hall, modular kitchen cupboard doors in kitchen. Cupboard and loft doors in Bedroom to match with wall colors.

I don't have the gift of choosing colors.

Any right guidance are appreciated

Comment: You probably want an interior designer who will get to know your likes and can point out the colours you will like, be able to match rooms and colours.   Be a lot better than asking us yahoos who don't even see your house or know what you like.

Comment: Most people can't afford the luxury of an interior designer. 'How to choose?' is not the same question as 'what to choose?' & I thought this would remain open, unlike a 'shopping question'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By heck, but this is broad.

We don't know anything about you, your house, your furniture or your environment. Is your house bright & airy or does it need brightness generating by swathes of colour? Do you live in cold Northern industrial town in a middle terrace with tiny windows, or by a beach in the Bahamas, with floor-to-ceiling windows, bamboo furniture & sea to the horizon?
What decorating schemes are used by your family, friends & neighbours? Do you feel you have to conform, or stand out? Are you a follower of fashion or willing to go it alone?

Some people consider 'matching' to be two shades of basically the same colour. Some people like contrasts.
Some can decorate an entire house to send you on a journey of colour, transitioning from area to area, others don't ever get beyond white woodwork & a non-committal pale for everything else.
Some revel in bright walls & distinct patterns, others would scream in horror & run away.
Some would consider a houseful of Ikea to be daring, others would go for dark woods, or antiques.

In general, it's considered that light colours will open up a space & make it airy, dark colours will enclose them more. Do you want open or cosy? Of course, it's hard to make a tiny room look open & some will think an attempt to brighten a small room by using only the very palest colours a desperate measure. Conversely to make a huge room cosy, you will need to break up the space in other ways, simply painting it really dark will look like a dungeon. You need to work with what you have, not fight it. Victorian colours in a modern semi will look forced, especially against modern furniture.

My bathroom is stone highlighted with aqua glass mini-tiles & also woodwork [think Roman baths]. The blues against warm yellows continues right through the house, but changes in impact as it transitions lighter & darker areas. The hallways - the darkest areas in the building - are bright sunshine yellow to make it look sunny even on dark days. The kitchen is sky blues against white, black & stainless steel against a very pale fake beechwood floor. Living room is pretty much orange against dark Mexican antique & mid-brown leather, with again aqua highlights & woodwork [different, paler aqua than anywhere else because the lighting is different, for similar reasons to why the kitchen is sky not aqua - work with the light not against it]. These areas are all tied together over a single dark blue heavy plain carpet, throughout all the non hard floor areas. This is all in a Victorian pile in North London.
You can get away with anything if you have the confidence ;) Friends of mine who live in Ikea & white love it, but wouldn't dare do it themselves.

Would you put a purple picture on an orange wall - or just not dare?
Does the idea of pale pine on white appeal to you, or make you yawn?

If you really can't envision it, find one of the big DIY stores that has an 'imaginarium' computer where you can test paints & papers in a  rendering from your own photographs.

Comment: Plus 1 for a superb opinion :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was helpful